# Does linkedin email find api still exist?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I’m trying to find out if linked in publishes an api to allow for email lookup by name. I know rocketreach.co pulls a lot of their data from linked in and I found this api: https://rapidapi.com/Denologica/api/linkedin2email/details

Any assistance would appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am the owner of the API. Linkedin no longer allows email lookups, but our data is obtained by linking disparate data sources by their common denominators, and then verifying the match accuracy by uploading random samples to LinkedIn as contacts and assessing the match rate. Ours is %97 accurate. Also, you pay only for successful requests; requests that do not return an email do not count towards your quota.